# The probability of A and B getting to know each other

Tags: probability

There is a large pool of $L$ numbers. Every person draws $s$ numbers at random out of $L$ with replacement. Suppose that
1) If A and B share at least one number, they can get to know each other; 
2) If A shares at least a number with a neighbor of B, called C, and B also shares a number with C, A and B can get to know each other through C.

Now, if B have altogether $n$ neighbors. My question is: What is the probability that A and B can get to know each other?

Comment: Sure about the tag (you might want to read it)?

Comment: The answer when $L^2\gg ns^4$ is approximately $ns^4/L^2$. Now, what did you try?

Comment: Would you like to give me a detailed reduction process? I encounter this problem during my an ongoing manuscript. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean the probability is near to zero?

Comment: Which part of `what did you try?` do you fail to get?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Case1：A and B share at least one number. This condition means the intersection in Fig.1 is not empty. We can obtain the probability that the intersection is empty, i.e., $\overline{P_{AB}} = \frac{C_L^{s}C_{L-s}^s}{(C_L^{s})^2}$. 
And thus $P_{AB}=1-\overline{P_{AB}}$.

Case 2: A and B don’t have same numbers, but they can get to know each other by a neighbor.
This condition means that both intersections in Fig.2 are not empty. The probability is $P_{ACB}=\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}\sum_{j=1}^{s-i}\frac{C_s^{i}C_s^{j}C_{L-2s}^{s-j-i}}{C_L^{s}}$.

Piecing the above two cases together, I think the probability that A and B can get to know each other is

$Pr_{AB}=P_{AB} + \overline{P_{AB}} \cdot [1-(1-P_{ACB})^n] = (1-\frac{C_L^{s}C_{L-s}^s}{(C_L^{s})^2}) + \frac{C_L^{s}C_{L-s}^s}{(C_L^{s})^2}\cdot [1-(1-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}\sum_{j=1}^{s-i}C_s^{i}C_s^{j}C_{L-2s}^{s-j-i}}{C_L^{s}})^{n}]$.

However, more concise results are still expected.